# passenger+nginx one app multi domains on different controller , how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a rails app, now it run on nginx+passenger.
I want something like these:
configure nginx to act as:
host1.com  is the app default server name
host2.com  use app/controller1 as root location
host3.com  use app/controller2 as root location

how to configure nginx?

my currently configure:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name mainsite.com; 
    root '/home/sandbox/railsapp/public';
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    passenger_spawn_method smart-lv2;
    passenger_min_instances 1;
}
```

and I need:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name sitename1.com;
}
```

make this sitename1.com point to mainsite.com/some-controller 
?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you should be able to add this to your `routes.rb`

```
constraints :subdomain => "sitename1" do
  root :to => "pages#sitename"
end
```

And then for that domain, add a CNAME record to sitename1.mydomain.com